# ui:inputDate select event not fired in firefox

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, event, date-picker

i emplemented a ui:datepicker lightning component and the select event is not fired when i select a date but only on firefox, chrome run correctly my code.

I've put a console.log in my controller method but nothing return.

I think the select event is not managed in the same way in Firefox & Chrome, but i don't fine solution so, if someone know how to fix that, i'll take it.

**Component**

```
<ui:inputDate label="" aura:id="changeWeek" displayDatePicker="true" 
select={!c.changeWeek}" value="{!v.changeWeek}" />
```

**Controller**

```
changeWeek : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getFirstDayofWeek(component);
    helper.getShiftList(component);
}
```

**Helper**

```
getFirstDayofWeek: function(component) {
    var daySelected = new Date(component.get('v.changeWeek'));
    var day = daySelected.getDay(), diff = daySelected.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -6:1); // adjust when day is sunday
    component.set("v.currentDate",new Date(daySelected.setDate(diff)));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two potential problems:

1) You are using the Select event to fire the controller. Try using the change event.

2) If that doesn't work, and I have found that it doesn't always work on the ui:inputDate fields, you can try setting up a handler:

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.nchangeWeek}" action="{!c.changeWeek}"/>
```

Comment: as of today change works just fine in winter17 orgs. seems like ui:inputDate has been significantly improved, format works now as well. it did not work few months ago. There are still some bugs, but in general it is  doing better.

Comment: thaks for your help i was thinking it doesn't work but it's just because you add a n before changeweek in the value attribute, now it work,

Answer (score 0):

the attribute to specify event hadnler for changes is "change". Selection of the day in datepicker will trigger "change".

```
<ui:inputDate label="" aura:id="changeWeek" displayDatePicker="true" change="{!c.changeWeek}" value="{!v.changeWeek}" />
```

the "select" event is for the text selection. so when you enter some text, then select few letters out of it - this event will happen. I guess this even is one out of many exposedvia API ti give you opportunity to select the month and then use arrows up/down to change it or change just the portion of the input.

here is the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputDate.htm)

the alternative way to listen for the change is to setup the change listener on attribute directly